# What is $\langle I\rangle$ in this text?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I've read the following:

> It is easy to see that given any independent set $I$ in $V$, the vertices of $V-I$ form a covering of $G$. Conversely, if $V-I$ forms a covering, then $\langle I\rangle$ must be empty; hence, it must be independent.

What is $\langle I\rangle$? I tried to search for it in the book I'm reading but couldn't. It doesn't have a notational index.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: Presumably, it is the subgraph of the graph induced by the vertices $I$. See [here](http://www2.fiu.edu/~ramsamuj/graphtheory/chap1.pdf)

Comment: If by empty the author means "has no edges", then I agree with user66081 - the subgraph induced by $I$ makes perfect sense.

Comment: @anorton [Ronald Gould: Graph Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Graph-Theory-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486498069).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments by [user66081](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/66081/user66081) and [Manuel Lafond](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/85136/manuel-lafond) are correct; $\langle I \rangle$ refers to the subgraph of $G$ induced by $I$.  In Gould's *Graph Theory*, the notation is introduced on page 6:

> Given a subset $S$ of $V(G)$, the *subgraph induced by $S$*, denoted $\langle S \rangle$, is that  graph with vertex set $S$ and edge set consisting of those edges of $G$ incident with two vertices of $S$.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think I had to go too much in the beginning to see that. I looked in the previous chapter various times, but didn't find it. Ah, I also didn't mention the book because there are no PDF's of them online (at least I didn't find it). Did you use Amazon's *Look Inside*?

Comment: @Vÿska I own the book. :)  When people suggested it might be the induced subgraph, I looked up "induced subgraph" in the index.